# Prove that ¬P → ( P → ( P → Q)) is a tautology without using truth tables

Tags: first-order-logic

I can't find a proper formula for this considering it's almost exclusively made up of implications. Can somebody help me?

EDIT: Sorry, I'm new to this site and still learning to use it. I've tried writing (P → Q) as (¬P ∨ Q) and then applying the distibutive laws but I feel like I've reached a dead end.

Comment: Tip: `A -> B` can be rewritten as `¬A ∨ B`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`P -> q` is the same as `no(p) OR q`
If you replace, in your expression :

`P -> (P -> Q)` is the same as `no(P) OR (no(P) OR Q)`

`no(P) -> P (P -> (P -> Q))` is the same as `no(no(p)) OR (no(P) OR (no(P) OR Q))`
which is the same as `p OR no(P) OR no(P) OR Q` which is always true ( because p or no(p) is always true)

Answer (score 0):

Simply:

```
!P -> (P -> (P -> Q))  apply implication
P v (!P v (P -> Q)))   P v !P is T
T v (...)              T v anything is T
T
```